# How to get the driver version using ODBC API without connecting to the database?

Tags: odbc, unixodbc, iodbc

We have code to connect to various databases and we get the driver version after connecting using the `SQLGetInfo()` call with the parameter `SQL_DRIVER_VER`.

However, we want the driver version in other cases too, e.g., before connecting, and in case of an error on trying to connect. The only way to get the driver version in these cases at least on Windows seems to be via the file metadata information of the driver DLL. The drivers on other platforms do not even have this file metadata.

So, is there a way to get the driver version using ODBC when we are not connected?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC API doesn't support this interrogation until the connection is live.

There are tricks you can bring to bear, such as those used by the [iODBC Administrator.app on OS X](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X).  You might look into [that source code](https://github.com/openlink/iODBC/).